# What is the time complexity of std::map

Tags: c++, g++

What is the time complexity of std::map? 
And will it degenerate in the worst case? 
Or it is decide by the implementation, we can't know it?

Comment: The time complexity for *what*? Anyway, have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: @juanchopanza Could it be anything other than data retrieval?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Yes. Data insertion for example. Or removal of elements.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Lookups are proportional to log(N). In a typical case (implementation as a red-black tree) the number of comparisons can be up to twice Log<sub>2</sub>N.

Insertions are *normally* proportional to Log<sub>2</sub>N as well--but there's a special provision made for when you're inserting a number of items that are already in order<sup>1</sup>. In this case, you can specify a "hint" for where an insertion is going to take place. When that hint is correct, each insertion is (amortized) O(1) instead of O(Log N), so inserting a range of items in sorted order is linear instead of N log(N). The hint you specify is an iterator to the position just after the item to be inserted.

For example, if you have a number of items in a file in sorted order, and you want to insert them into the map, you can specify `your_map.end()` as the "hint", and building the map will have O(N) complexity instead of O(N Log N) complexity.

---

<sub>1. Technically, this applies anytime you insert items, not just when you're inserting them in order--but by far the most common case where you have a reasonable "hint" available is when you're inserting items in order.</sub>

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how exactly we can update a map with a very long list of sorted numbers? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This depends on the implementation, you can't associate a complexity of any kind to `std::map` just by looking at the language specs.

Usually an `std::map` is implemented as a [Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) and you can find all info about the Big-O properties of this kind of containers [here](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

Notably there are less popular alternatives to the standard libraries shipped with popular compilers such as `msvc` or `gcc`, that implements this kind of containers with `B-tree`s, this leads to lower memory usage due to the fact that a B-tree usually occupy less memory that an RB-tree.

For example [click here](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/).

Comment: Yes, you can associate a complexity with `std::map` operations because they are written into the specification. In particular, a "sorted array" implementation of `std::map` is non-conformant for this reason (as well as the pointer/iterator invalidation requirements, too).

Comment: @Pseudonym and what the actual definition is ?

Comment: I'm looking at the January 2012 draft (which is identical to ISO 2011 apart from minor copyedits), section [map.access]: "Complexity: logarithmic."

Answer (score 4):

Usually the time complexity is specified for operations. In your case the **lookup** and **insert** seems relevant.

See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/complexity.html for the guaranteed complexties of the STL containers. And this http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/AssociativeContainer.html on the Associative Containers.

Another source is found here:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/ --> **Logarithmic** in size.
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/ --> If a single element is inserted, **logarithmic** in size in general, but amortized constant if a hint is given and the position given is the optimal.

the lookup of std::map is log(number of elements in the map).

Comment: The two first links are dead

Comment: this is exactly why you do not add links to your answer but summarize their conentent instead

Answer (score 4):

if you're asking about the lookup time compexity for std::map then that would be O(log(n)) since the stl implemented the std::map library as a Tree (binary tree) datastructure.

More information here: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Here is also the commonly used std::unordered_map, which would be your hashmap (no ordering hence) with a O(1) look up speed, however, using more memory than the Tree per the design of the data structure.